# How to check the existence of a user in Discord.js without errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord, discord.js

**Explain**

I am developing a user verification bot.
Within the requirements I need to remove the **user reactions** on a specific message, but removing the reactions discord.js triggers the `messageReactionRemove` event and causes another function to be executed that sets the roles to a user.

**Problem/Error**

The problem happens when a user leaves the server, discord.js removes the reactions but in turn triggers another event `messageReactionRemove` and my bot blows up with an error called "Uknow Member"

**Codes**

Listener when an user leaves the server:

```js
// All this code works fine :)

client.on("guildMemberRemove", async (member) => {
 warn(`El usuario ${member.user.username} abandono el servidor`);

 try {
   const channel = await client.channels.fetch(CHANNELS.VERIFICATION_CHANNEL);
   const message = await channel.messages.fetch(
     MESSAGES.BOT_VERIFICATION_MESSAGE_ID
   );

   message.reactions.cache.map((reaction) => {

     // After removing the reaction, discord.js fires the event "messageReactionRemove"
     reaction.users.remove(member.user.id);
   });
 } catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
 }
});
```

Listener when an user remove a reaction from a message:

```js
  if (!user.bot) {
    try {
      const channelId = reaction.message.channelId;
      const messageId = reaction.message.id;
      const emojiName = reaction.emoji.name;
      const userExists = await getMember(user.id); // <-- This explodes in an error

      if (!userExists) {
        warn(`El usuario ${user.username} no existe en el servidor`);
        return;
      }

      if (
        channelId === CHANNELS.VERIFICATION_CHANNEL &&
        messageId === MESSAGES.BOT_VERIFICATION_MESSAGE_ID &&
        emojiName === EMOJIS.VERIFICATION_EMOJI
      ) {
        addTownLoyalRoleToNewUsers(reaction, user);
      }
      // other messages validations ...

    } catch (err) {
      error(err.message, err);
    }
  }
```

Code for add the verification role:

```js
const addTownLoyalRoleToNewUsers = async (reaction, user) => {
  const member = await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user.id); // <-- This also blows up in an error
  const townRoyalUsersLength = await getUsersLengthByRole(
    ROLES.TOW_LOYAL_ROLE_ID
  );

  if (townRoyalUsersLength <= MAX_LENGTH_TOW_LOYAL_USERS) {
    member.roles.add(ROLES.TOW_LOYAL_ROLE_ID);
  } else {
    member.roles.add(ROLES.VERIFIED_ROLE_ID);
  }

  const otherRoles = ROLES.AFTER_VERIFICATION();
  if (otherRoles.length) member.roles.add(otherRoles);
};
```

**Error images**
Error when an user leaves a server
[image: discord.js error 1]

Interestingly when the user leaves, the `guildMemberRemove` event still owns the nonexistent user
[image: discord.js error 2]

Comment: Hi, what is `getMember()`? I don't see it defined or imported anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, you can see all my utils methods here:
https://pastebin.com/ZdJw03qC

Comment: You can add a try catch when fetching the member in `getMember()` so you can catch the error and return undefined/null. Would you like me to add that as an answer? The other way is to fetch the entire member list and check if the member exists there, but that wastes a lot of memory.

Comment: good idea, I was trying to run a ```fecth``` to request a user in the guild to check if it exists but it still throws me an "Uknow Member" error.
I thought about using the cache to save resources but the cache is a problem because it stores old data. I think it is not possible to do what I am looking for without an error occurring :(

Comment: When a user joins the server and checks out and leaves that error occurs when trying to search for a user, how can I prevent the ```messageReactionRemove``` event from being triggered when I remove the reactions in ```guildMemberRemove```?

Comment: @LibardoRengifo please indicate if one of the answers below resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only remove the member who is leaving, then this line of code should do the trick, add it to your `guildMemberRemove` event

```js
client.channels.cache.get('ChannelIdWithMessage').messages.fetch('MessageIdToRemoveReactionsFrom').then((message) => {
message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.remove(member.user.id))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to discord.js you should know, there is the Discord API, which is where those errors come from, and then there are the objects, which make interacting with the Discord API easier.

I'm assuming that your `getMember()` function tries to fetch the member from the API by ID (`guild.members.fetch(id)`). Note the user is *not* "non-existent", it's the `GuildMember`. The object is simply data from the event, but you can't interact with it in the API. You seem to expect the `getMember()` function to return a falsy value, like null or undefined, if the member is not found. Instead, it gets a 404 and rejects.

Instead, use a `.catch()` like this:

```js
const userExists = await getMember(user.id).catch(() => null); // null if rejected
```